# Toshiba 2TB External Drive can not format in Windows 10

Tags: format

The new Toshiba 2TB External drive can not format in Windows 10.
It was my mistake to run Rufus app to allow format Toshiba 2TB External drive. However, that process incomplete. Looking for advise. Thanks.

Comment: Describe exactly what happens when you try to format. A screenshot will help.

Comment: Use the native disk management software(e.g. *diskmgmt.msc* for Windows) or a third-party tool such as DiskGenius to delete all partitions, then create a single partition, probably NTFS for most use.